# Why is using sorting (O(n log n) complexity) to find the majority element faster than using a HashMap (O(n) complexity)?

Tags: java, performance, hashmap, quicksort

Majority element question:

> *Given an array of size n, find the majority element. The majority element is the element that appears more than **⌊ n/2 ⌋** times.
>   You may assume that the array is non-empty and the majority element always exist in the array.*

```
// Solution1 - Sorting ----------------------------------------------------------------
    class Solution {
        public int majorityElement(int[] nums) {
            Arrays.sort(nums);
            return nums[nums.length/2];
        }
    }

// Solution2 - HashMap ---------------------------------------------------------------
class Solution {
    public int majorityElement(int[] nums) {
        // int[] arr1 = new int[nums.length];
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(100);  
        Integer k = new Integer(-1);
        try{
            for(int i : nums){
                if(map.containsKey(i)){
                    map.put(i, map.get(i)+1);
                }
                else{
                    map.put(i, 1);
                }
            }
            for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
                if(entry.getValue()>(nums.length/2)){
                    k = entry.getKey();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error");
        }
        return k;    
    }
}
```

The Arrays.sort() function is implemented in Java using QuickSort and has **O(n log n)** time complexity.

On the other hand, using HashMap to find the majority element has only **O(n)** time complexity.

Hence, **solution 1 (sorting)** should take longer than **solution 2 (HashMap)**, but when I was doing the question on LeetCode, the average time taken by solution 2 is much more (almost 8 times more) than solution 1.

Why is that the case? I'm really confused.....

Is the size of the test case the reason? Will solution 2 become more efficient when the number of elements in the test case increases dramatically?

Comment: I'd bet on the size of the test case being the reason; that n would have to get pretty large before the `HashMap` would win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big O isn't a measure of actual performance. It's only going to give you an idea of how your performance will evolve in comparison to n.

Practically, an algorithms in O(n.logn) will eventually be slower than O(n) for some n. But that n might be 1, 10, 10^6 or even 10^600 - at which point it's probably irrelevant because you'll never run into such a data set - or you won't have enough hardware for it.

Software engineers have to consider both actual performance and performance at the practical limit. For example hash map lookup is in theory faster than an unsorted array lookup... but then most arrays are small (10-100 elements) negating any O(n) advantage due the extra code complexity.

You could certainly optimize your code a bit, but in this case you're unlikely to change the outcome for small n unless you introduce another factor (e.g. artificially slow down the time per cycle with a constant).

(I wanted to find a good metaphor to illustrate, but it's harder than expected...)

Comment: Thanks for the information:D so is there any way to measure the actual performance for certain scenario? By analyzing the codes line by line? Otherwise how can we know which algorithm we should use, as we cant predict how good they will perform? 

Comment: We can measure the actual performance: that's benchmarking (what you did). But it's quite hard, as there are a lot of behaviors to account for (look up Java microbenchmarking for fun). Big O is useful there to translate benchmark performance to your expected production data set (which quite often also a best guess).  You could also look (or guess) at how the program actually compiles or execute, but that's impractical beyond trivial complexity (still useful for tight loops). In the end, it's a combination of expertise and pragmatism - (look up "premature optimization is the root of all evil").

Comment: Practical example: customer complains performance is terrible on 100M records. Developer claims they benchmarked it fine on 100 records. Algorithm is O(n^2). Expert facepalms.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the test cases, some test cases will be faster in HashMap while others not.

**Why is that?** The *Solution 1* grantee in worst case *O(N log<sub>2</sub> N)*, but the HashMap *O(N . (M + R))* where M is the cost of collisions and R the cost of resizing the array.

HashMap uses an array named `table` of the nodes internally, and it resizes different times when the input increase or shrink. And you assigned it with an initial capacity of 100.

**So let see what happens?** Java uses Separate chaining for resolving the collisions and some test cases may have lots of collisions which lead to consuming lots of time when a query or update the hashmap.

**Conclusion** the implementation of hashmap is affected by two factors: 1. Resize the table array based on the input size 2. How many collision appears in the input